# How to get the most recent records from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores some reports about an url and they have a field like created_date. The same report can be generated (and stored) multiple times because the values can change. How can I get the url reports, but just the most recent ones?

My table (page_report):

```
id INT PK
url VARCHAR(255)
created_date TIMESTAMP
```

Sample data:

```
id    url          created_date
1     google.com   2016-11-01
2     google.com   2016-11-05
3     bing.com     2016-11-03
4     bing.com     2016-11-06
```

I need:

```
id    url          created_date
1     google.com   2016-11-05
2     bing.com     2016-11-06
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM page_report r1
LEFT JOIN page_report r2 ON r1.url = r2.url AND r1.created_date < r2.created_date
WHERE r2.url IS NULL;
```

But it's very slow. Is there any better way?

Hope I made myself clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: Query the Max(created_date).

Comment: If the URL changes... how do you know which records relate to eachother?

Comment: Plz provide sample data and your desire output.

Comment: The url does not change, xQbert.
I'll provide some more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept with this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.url FROM page_report r1
    LEFT JOIN page_report r2 ON r1.url = r2.url AND r1.created_date < r2.created_date
    WHERE r2.url IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to generate a date set of the max records by Some ID / Logical Key.

If I assume a field called ID is the grouping mechanism for the urls...

```
SELECT T1.URL, T1.Created_Date
FROM TableEName T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Created_Date) CD, ID
            FROM TableName 
            GROUP BY ID)
 on T1.ID = T2.ID
and T1.Created_Date = T2.CD
```

The trick here is how do we know a URL "Changed"  would they have the same ID or some other attribute that would remain constant over time?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` and then group by `url` and select `MAX(created_date)`.

```
SELECT t.url, MAX(t.created_date) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2) t
GROUP BY t.url
```

See the [myql's UNION documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Create a Rank Function for latest Create Date. Something like below.

```
select * from (select distinct DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY url   ORDER BY B.CreatedDate desc) Rnk, t.url  )
where rnk =1
```